# What does String(42) do in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, methods, constants

Why cant I do this?

```
>> s = String
>> s(42)
s(42)
NoMethodError: undefined method `s' for main:Object
        from (irb):86
        from /home/sam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/bin/irb:17:in `<main>'
```

Next.

```
>> String.new 42
String.new 42
TypeError: can't convert Fixnum into String
        from (irb):90:in `initialize'
        from (irb):90:in `new'
        from (irb):90
        from /home/sam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/bin/irb:17:in `<main>'
```

How does String() convert a Fixnum to a String if String.new cannot? I assume String() calls to_s. But then what is String.new looking for besides a string to copy? Is new an alias for dup?

Comment: Your two questions have nothing to do with each other. Please split them into two questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason that `s(42)` does not work in your example, is that there is a constant named `String` (which points to the class) as well as a method named `String` (which converts the argument to a string using `to_s`). When you do `s = String`, `s` will now point to the same class as `String`. However when you call `s(42)`, ruby will look for a method named `s`, which does not exist and you get an error.

The key here is that in ruby there can be a variable or constant and a method with the same name without them having anything to do with each other.

The reason for the differing behaviour between `String(42)` and `String.new(42)` is that `String` calls `to_s` and `String.new` calls `to_str`.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a string with the value "42" in it, then `s = "42"` is all you need to do.

If you already have a Fixnum that you want to store as a string, `s = some_fixnum.to_s` will do it.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is just an academic question. I think (and hope) that Mr. Danielson ordinarily follows the conventional `""` and `to_s` approaches.